# In Spark, how do I use groupBy with spark-submit?

Tags: python, group-by, apache-spark

I have a spark python script that has a groupBy in it. In particular, the structure is

```
import operator
result = sc.textFile(...).map(...).groupBy(...).map(...).reduce(operator.add)
```

When I run this in an ipython pyspark shell, it works just fine. However, when I try to script it and run it through spark-submit, I get a `pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle builtin <type 'method_descriptor'>` error citing the groupBy as the concern. Is there a known workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there's a lot that pickle can't do, including lambdas. I was doing some of that and needed to be more careful.

Comment: Spark uses its own fork of `cloudpickle` for extending Pickle to support additional types, including lambdas.  If you can come up with a small, standalone example of a Spark program that fails with this pickling error, could you open an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK so we can fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: Hey Josh. I ended up changing the structure of the program but am running into a consistent error that I wrote up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726780/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-submit-and-pyspark. Do you mind taking a look at that please?