# Spark pyspark vs spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The documentation on spark-submit says the following:

> The spark-submit script in Spark’s bin directory is used to launch
>   applications on a cluster.

Regarding the pyspark it says the following:

> You can also use bin/pyspark to launch an interactive Python shell.

This question may sound stupid, but when i am running the commands though `pyspark` they also run on the "cluster", right? They do not run on the master node only, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between spark-submit and pyspark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726780/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-submit-and-pyspark)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no practical difference between these two. If not configured otherwise both will execute code in a local mode. If master is configured (either by `--master` command line parameter or `spark.master` configuration) corresponding cluster will be used to execute the program.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using EMR , there are three things

1. using pyspark(or spark-shell)
2. using spark-submit without using --master and --deploy-mode
3. using spark-submit and using --master and --deploy-mode

although using all the above three will run the application in spark cluster, there is a difference how the driver program works.

- in 1st and 2nd the driver will be in client mode whereas in 3rd the
  driver will also be in the cluster.
- in 1st and 2nd, you will have to wait untill one application complete
  to run another, but in 3rd you can run multiple applications in
  parallel.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding a clarification that others have not addressed (you may already know this, but it was unclear from the wording of your question):

> ..when i am running the commands though pyspark they also run on the "cluster", right? They do not run on the master node only, right?

As with `spark-submit`, **standard Python code will run only on the driver**. When you call operations through the various `pyspark` APIs, you will trigger transformations or actions that will be registered/executed on the cluster.

As others have pointed out, `spark-submit` can also launch jobs in cluster mode. In this case, driver still executes standard Python code, but the driver is **a different machine** to the one that you call `spark-submit` from.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pyspark compare to Scala spark and Java Spark have extreme differences, for Python spark in only support YARN for scheduling the cluster.
2. If you are running python spark on a local machine, then you can use pyspark. If in the cluster, use the spark-submit.
3. If you have any dependencies in your python spark job, you need a zip file for submission.