# Pyspark: spark-submit not working like CLI

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark to load data from a TSV file and save it as parquet file as well save it as a persistent SQL table.

When I run it line by line through pyspark CLI, it works exactly like expected. When I run it as as an application using spark-submit it runs without any errors but I get strange results: 1. the data is overwritten instead of appended. 2. When I run SQL queries against it I get no data returned even though the parquet files are several gigabytes in size (what I expect). Any suggestions?

Code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

csv_file = '/srv/spark/data/input/ipfixminute2018-03-28.tsv'
parquet_dir = '/srv/spark/data/parquet/ipfixminute'

sc = SparkContext(appName='import-ipfixminute')
spark = SQLContext(sc)

fields = [StructField('time_stamp', TimestampType(), True),
                StructField('subscriberId', StringType(), True),
                StructField('sourceIPv4Address', StringType(), True),
                StructField('destinationIPv4Address', StringType(), True),
                StructField('service',StringType(), True),
                StructField('baseService',StringType(), True),
                StructField('serverHostname', StringType(), True),
                StructField('rat', StringType(), True),
                StructField('userAgent', StringType(), True),
                StructField('accessPoint', StringType(), True),
                StructField('station', StringType(), True),
                StructField('device', StringType(), True),
                StructField('contentCategories', StringType(), True),
                StructField('incomingOctets', LongType(), True),
                StructField('outgoingOctets', LongType(), True),
                StructField('incomingShapingDrops', IntegerType(), True),
                StructField('outgoingShapingDrops', IntegerType(), True),
                StructField('qoeIncomingInternal', DoubleType(), True),
                StructField('qoeIncomingExternal', DoubleType(), True),
                StructField('qoeOutgoingInternal', DoubleType(), True),
                StructField('qoeOutgoingExternal', DoubleType(), True),
                StructField('incomingShapingLatency', DoubleType(), True),
                StructField('outgoingShapingLatency', DoubleType(), True),
                StructField('internalRtt', DoubleType(), True),
                StructField('externalRtt', DoubleType(), True),
                StructField('HttpUrl',StringType(), True)]

schema = StructType(fields)
df = spark.read.load(csv_file, format='csv',sep='\t',header=True,schema=schema,timestampFormat='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
df = df.drop('all')
df = df.withColumn('date',to_date('time_stamp'))
df.write.saveAsTable('test2',mode='append',partitionBy='date',path=parquet_dir)
```

Comment: When you run spark-submit, you delegate the execution to your cluster (Spark? YARN?) on which you may be misssing dependencies. See also this discussion
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910014/spark-pyspark-vs-spark-submit

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Spark can access Hive table from pyspark but not from spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36359812)

Comment: Try to insert time.sleep(600) at the end of code, go to Spark UI and check out logs.

Comment: @user8371915 Yes that was the same issue! Although in my case it wasn't throwing any errors so it was hard to understand what was the root cause. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @user8371915 suggested it is similar to this:

[Spark can access Hive table from pyspark but not from spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36359812)

I needed to replace

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

with

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
```

This resolved this issue.