# Pyspark dataframe store to MongoDB error

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

The code works fine with the `pyspark` shell but when I'm trying to write a program in Java or Scala, I'm getting exceptions.

What is the best way to store spark dataframe to MongoDB using python?

- pyspark version- 2.2.0
- MongoDB version- 3.4
- Python 2.7
- Java - jdk-9

Here is my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

my_spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll") \
    .getOrCreate()

dataframe = my_spark.read.csv('auto-data.csv', header=True)
dataframe.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
    .mode("append").option("database", "auto").option("collection", "autod").save()
```

and the [snapshot of my csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhPeA.png).

and the [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVZyS.png):

I tried after installing `mongo-spark` library from github, yet getting the same result.

Comment: You need to provide the required jars packages using `--jars`  options while submitting the script. Error clearly points that , it is not able to find the required class.

Comment: I pretty much tried that. I also put the mongo-spark which contains the jar files. But still I couldn't solve this issue.

Comment: Post the full command you are using to run the script. It might be helpful in learning what you are missing.

Comment: Just a wild thought. Can you fallback to JDK8. I don't think Spark is compatible yet with JDK9.

Then, try again and see if you get the same errors.

Comment: Use Java 8 or below.

Comment: @ashwinids I used python "filename.py" to run the script. I tried same in pyspark shell it worked. But, not with python script.

Comment: You have to use `spark-submit` shell script to run the python script. see this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120011/using-spark-submit-with-python-main) to understand how to run python scripts and attach dependency jars

Answer (score 0):

You need to download all the dependencies and store at a location , "/opt/jars" in the following example
Jars required
1. mongo-spark-connector_2.12-2.4.0.jar
2. mongodb-driver-3.10.1.jar
3. mongo-hadoop-core-1.3.0.jar (Incase running spark on yarn)

```
sudo wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.12/2.4.0/mongo-spark-connector_2.12-2.4.0.jar
sudo wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.10.1/mongodb-driver-3.10.1.jar
sudo wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-hadoop-core/1.3.0/mongo-hadoop-core-1.3.0.jar
```

Then execute with the following command

```
spark-submit --jars "/opt/jar/*.jar" --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0 <your file>.py arg1 arg2
```