# Java Object not callable while using sparkmeasure

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I am trying to use Sparkmeausre to check the performance of my Pyspark code. I am using Pycharm Community edition on windows 10, with Pyspark properly configured. I did "**pip install sparkmeasure**" and sparkmeasure was sucessfully installed. Now when I am trying to run this snippet of code.

```
from pyspark import  SparkConf , SparkContext
from pyspark.context import  SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import  SparkSession
from sparkmeasure import StageMetrics


sc = SparkContext(master = "local" , appName = "sparkdemo")
spark = SparkSession(sc)
sm = StageMetrics(spark)
```

I am getting the error.

```
File "C:/Users/nj123/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/sparkdemo.py", line 9, in <module>
sm = StageMetrics(spark)
File "C:\Users\nj123\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\sparkmeasure\stagemetrics.py", line 15, in __init__
self.stagemetrics = self.sc._jvm.ch.cern.sparkmeasure.StageMetrics(self.sparksession._jsparkSession)
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

How to resolve this error and to configure sparkmeasure to Pycharm correctly?

Comment: I have faced a similar issue in the past. Put the spark_measure jar in your `spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/jars` directory (use the spark version which you have downloaded) and invoke the  python script through spark-submit on commandline. That's the only way I could get it work. Don't use Pycharm way to start a spark job.

Comment: @user238607 Thanks. I put my spark jar folder in "C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\jars" which contains all jars file. Now, what command should I type on cmd to execute this jar and how to invoke python script ?

Comment: @user238607 I did as you told, moved my jar file to the desired location and re ran the code in Pycharm terminal. It worked perfectly without any issues. Thanks a lot. Just curious to know, how you resolved this issue when you faced it first time!

Comment: You don't have to invoke the functions in the jar directly. Your python code will do that. Here's how you can submit pyspark job through spark-submit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120011/using-spark-submit-with-python-main

Comment: Okay. But I did it without spark - submit. Just ran the program in pycharm and it worked properly.

Comment: Please make sure to write your solution in the answer so that others will have a solution for future reference.

Comment: @user238607 Thanks. I posted the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @user238607. Here are the steps I performed to resolve this issue.

```
1. First download Sparkmeasure jar file from Maven Central.

2. Then move this jar file to the spark jar folder. Mine location was, C:\Spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\jars

3. Now, Go to pycharm again, and rerun the same code.
```

[Link to download the jar file.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.cern.sparkmeasure/spark-measure_2.12/0.17)