# Run Spark application with custom number of cores and memory size

Tags: apache-spark, command-line, pyspark, distributed-computing

I'm totally new at this, so I don't understand really well how it's doing. 
I need to run spark on my machine  (login with ssh) and set up memory 60g, and 6 cores for execution. 
This is what I've tried.

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 60g --executor-cores 6
```

And this is what I got:

```
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing application resource.
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkArgument(CommandBuilderUtils.java:253)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitArgs(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:160)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:276)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:151)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:87)
```

So, I guess there is some things to add to this code line for running and I have no idea what.

Comment: You are missing `--class package.ClassName` and the JAR that you want to submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 60g --executor-cores 6
```

you don't specify which the entry point and your application!

Check the [spark-submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit) documentation, which states:

Some of the commonly used options are:

- --class: The entry point for your application (e.g. org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi)
- --master: The master URL for the cluster (e.g. spark://23.195.26.187:7077)
- --deploy-mode: Whether to deploy your driver on the worker nodes (cluster) or locally as an external client (client) (default: client)
  †
- --conf: Arbitrary Spark configuration property in key=value format. For values that contain spaces wrap “key=value” in quotes (as shown).
- application-jar: Path to a bundled jar including your application and
  all dependencies. The URL must be globally visible inside of your
  cluster, for instance, an hdfs:// path or a file:// path that is
  present on all nodes.
- application-arguments: Arguments passed to the main method of your
  main class, if any

For Python applications, simply pass a .py file in the place of `<application-jar>` instead of a JAR, and add Python .zip, .egg or .py files to the search path with `--py-files`.

Here is an example that takes some JARs and a python file (I didn't include your additional parameters for simplicity):

```
./spark-submit --jars myjar1.jar,myjar2.jar --py-files path/to/my/main.py arg1 arg2
```

---

> I hope I can entry to spark shell (with that much memory and cores) and type code in there

Then you need `pyspark`, not `spark-submit`! [What is the difference between spark-submit and pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726780/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-submit-and-pyspark)

So what you really want to do is this:

```
pyspark --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 60g --executor-cores 6
```

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand. I have a lot of csv files on my machine and I need to filter them and save to pandas. So, I don't have any file to run, I hope I can entry to spark shell (with that much memory and cores) and type code in there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you total number of cores=6 and total memory is 60GB. The parameeters

```
--executor-memory
--executor-cores
```

are actually for each executor inside spark. probably you should try

--executor-memory 8G
--executor-cores 1
this will create about 6 executors of 8Gb each (total 6*8 = 48GB). The rest 12 GB for operating system processing and metadata.

Comment: No, no. I have about 12 cores, maybe more,  and a lot of memory, 60 gb is about a half of each.

Comment: in that case, can you just try spark-submit and with just one parameter(with the pythonscript) and see if you get any error.

Comment: and yes, you havnt added the script that you want to run in spark-submit.

Comment: I find solution, thank you. I just need to type pyspark instead spark-submit. :)

Comment: spark-submit for submitting a job, pyspark is for interactive spark access