# Exec pyspark standalone script without spark-submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I am new to installing spark on a Linux machine and have possibly a basic question : 
I have installed Spark version 1.6.0 and Python 2.6.6

In spark interactive mode, I am able to run these simple commands to count lines in the README.md file.

However, I want to be able to create a standalone Python script and achieve the same result, but am getting errors.

My python code in **test.py** -

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("word count").setMaster("local[3]")
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)


    rdd = sc.textFile("/opt/spark/README.md")

    print(rdd.count())
```

If I run this as -

```
spark-submit ./test.py
```

I get a correct result.

```
95
```

My question is, why can't I run this as just -

```
./test.py
```

since I am importing pyspark and SparkContext in my python script.

I get the error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 8, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 188, in _do_init
    self._javaAccumulator = self._jvm.PythonAccumulatorV2(host, port)
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

I know I'm missing adding some jars somewhere, as per my google searches, but I don't think I understand whats exactly going on here. I would appreciate if someone could point me to a basic tutorial on how to setup spark variables and CLASSPATH.

I already read this question, but its not as much detail -

[What is the difference between spark-submit and pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726780/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-submit-and-pyspark)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on two pieces of information:

- > I have installed Spark version 1.6.0 and Python 2.6.6
- > ```
  > self._javaAccumulator = self._jvm.PythonAccumulatorV2(host, port)
  > ```

These parts suggest that you misconfigured your Spark installation:

- You believe to use Spark 1.6 (this seems to be the version of jars in your path).
- Python package in the path uses code introduced in Spark 2.1.0 ([SPARK-16861](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16861)).

Most likely this is the result of incorrectly set `PYTHONPATH` or equivalent environment variable.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I'm looking for, how to configure Spark and Python environment variables. The tutorials I'm following, do not mention this in the steps.